# Data fetch returns null to caller

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have the following code in `home.dart`

```
void initState() {
    super.initState();
    dbServ.getUserData().then((value){
      print(value);
    });
}
```

and the following code in `dbserv.dart`

```
Future getUserData() async {
    await firestoreInstance.collection("userData").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get().then((value){
      //print(value.data());
      return value.data();
    });
}
```

Whenever I run the code, the output from the print statement in `home.dart` initState is always `null`. But when I try to print from within the `getUserData()` function  in `dbserv.dart` I am able to get the correct data. Pleas let me know what is causing this behaviour and how do I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not returning anything from the top-level code inside `getUserData`.

It should look something like this:

```
Future getUserData() async {
    const value = await firestoreInstance.collection("userData").doc(firebaseUser.uid).get();
    return value.data();
}
```

Comment: It worked. I thought the return statement inside the `then` would work the same. Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: It could work, but only if you also `return` a value from the top-level code inside `getUserdata()`. But since you're already using `async` and `await`, I find it more readable to have the code without a `then()` here.